# how to make invisible text like ad*** and us*** using PHP

Tags: php, html

```html
$url12 = explode(".", parse_url($row['url'], PHP_URL_HOST)); 
$tld = end($url12);
   <td id='url'> .".$url." </td>
```

Hello i need to hide the last text(url) and replase it with *** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ideas from this code

```
$text="hello stackoverflow";
$str=str_split($text,(strLen($text)/4);
echo $str[0]."***".last($str);
```